# Can't connect to external database with Zend Framework but mysql_connect works

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, pdo, zend-db, mysql-error-1045

I am trying to connect to multiple databases with Zend Framework. When I connect using the same credentials with mysql_connect, it works just fine. When I connect with Zend I get

```
"Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access 
denied for user 'xxxx'@'localhost' (using password: YES)' in C:\wamp\www\zend\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php on line 144"
```

I was following the tutorial at http://www.amazium.com/blog/using-different-databases-with-zend-framework

Here is my application.ini:

```
resources.multidb.db1.adapter = "PDO_MYSQL"
resources.multidb.db1.dbname = "xxxxx"
resources.multidb.db1.username = "xxxxxx"
resources.multidb.db1.password = "xxxxxx"
resources.multidb.db1.hostname = "localhost"
resources.multidb.db1.charset = "UTF8"
resources.multidb.db1.default = true

resources.multidb.db3.adapter = "PDO_MYSQL"
resources.multidb.db3.dbname = "xxxxxx"
resources.multidb.db3.username = "xxxxxx"
resources.multidb.db3.password = "xxxxxx"
resources.multidb.db3.hostname = "xxxxx"
resources.multidb.db3.charset = "UTF8"
resources.multidb.db3.default = false
```

Here is my Bootstrap.php:

```
/**
 * Add databases to the registry
 */
public function _initDbRegistry()
{
    $this->bootstrap('multidb');
    $multidb = $this->getPluginResource('multidb');
    Zend_Registry::set('local', $multidb->getDb('db1'));
    Zend_Registry::set('db2', $multidb->getDb('db2'));
    Zend_Registry::set('db3', $multidb->getDb('db3'));
}
```

Here is my model:

```
class ModuleName_Model_ModelName extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_name;
    protected $_schema;
    protected $_db; // changed from $_adapter in tutorial for Zend 1.11

    public function init() 
    {
        $this->_name = 'contacts';
        $this->_schema  = 'xxxxx';
        $this->_db = Zend_Registry::get('db3');
    }
}
```

Here is where I'm calling it in my controller:

```
$model = new ModuleName_Model_ModelName();
$this->view->output= $model->fetchAll();
```

I have connectected via phpmyadmin, mysql workbench, and using plain old mysql_connect by copying and pasting the same username and password. There is no doubt that the username and password are correct. Anyone have any idea what I could be doing wrong in Zend that is throwing the access denied error?

Ok, thanks - I tried your suggestion, Midhun:

```
Zend_Debug::dump($model->getAdapter()->getConfig());
```

and I did get correct output.

Any other ideas?

Comment: When I tried to get the multidb resource to work many ZF versions ago I gave up and wrote my own. That said, try following the [manual's example](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.available-resources.html#zend.application.available-resources.multidb)

Answer (score 1):

try out this for a debug and check if the adapter is exactly what you expect it to be...

```
$model = new ModuleName_Model_ModelName();
Zend_Debug::dump($model->getAdapter()->getConfig());
```