# How to get records from outside database in Zend?

Tags: php, database, zend-framework

I am using following configuration in application.ini for database;

```
resources.db.adapter = "Mysqli"
resources.db.params.host = "localhost"
resources.db.params.username = "root"
resources.db.params.password = "root"
resources.db.params.dbname = "dbname"
resources.db.params.charset = "utf8"
```

After that using standard Model/Mapper/DbTable classes to access database like [this](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.create-model.html)

Now I want to access some other database but with same table structure as local database. How can I switch my database for that specific controller/action where I want to show data for other database.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [Zend_Application_Resource_Multidb](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.available-resources.html#zend.application.available-resources.multidb)

There is an example of its usage [here](http://www.amazium.com/blog/using-different-databases-with-zend-framework), under the heading `Different user/host`.

Similar question(s) on Stackoverflow

1. [Can't connect to external database with Zend Framework but mysql connect works.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200492/cant-connect-to-external-database-with-zend-framework-but-mysql-connect-works)

EDIT: I also discovered that even when I had the following lines in my Model inherited from `Zend_Db_Table_Abstract` it was not connecting to the remote DB.

```
protected $_schema  = 'otherdb';
protected $_adapter = 'db_remote';
```

So I checked this function in Zend_Db_Table_Abstract

```
protected function _setupDatabaseAdapter()
    {
        if (! $this->_db) {
            $this->_db = self::getDefaultAdapter();
            if (!$this->_db instanceof Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract) {
                require_once 'Zend/Db/Table/Exception.php';
                throw new Zend_Db_Table_Exception('No adapter found for ' . get_class($this));
            }
        }
    }
```

If its the same for you, add the following lines to your constructor:

```
public function __construct() {
    $front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
    $bootstrap = $front->getParam('bootstrap');
    $resource = $bootstrap->getPluginResource('multidb');
    $this->_db = $resource->getDb('chdpg');
}
```

Comment: I am following [this](http://www.amazium.com/blog/using-different-databases-with-zend-framework). It is working with multiple databases but with both databases on same server. But when both databases are on different servers then it is causing problems and not accessing remote database.